# Why can't I change this BufferedImage?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

For some reason, I can change a buffered image by using setRGB but not by using the actual int array in the raster:

## This works

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
        int gray = (int) (MathUtil.noise(x, y) * 255); //I have tested the noise function,   and know it works fine
        img.setRGB(x, y, gray << 16 | gray << 8 | gray);
    }
}
```

## This does not

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] data = ((DataBufferInt) img.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();

for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
        int gray = (int) (MathUtil.noise(x, y) * 255); //I have tested the noise function, and know it works fine
        data[x + y * 32] = gray << 16 | gray << 8 | gray;
    }
}
```

## Noise function:

```
public static float noise(int x, int y) {
    int n = x + y * 57;
    n = (n << 13) ^ n;
    return Math.abs((1.0f - ((n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0f));
}
```

## EDIT

Nevermind I fixed it. I needed to use getRaster :P

Comment: @5gon12eder No error, the image is supposed to be incoherent noise, but turns out black

Comment: why are you re-inventing the wheel (via your `noise` function)?

Comment: @specializt Because I have found no method in java that actually does this (without initializing a new Random every time)

Comment: um ... thats what they keywords `static final` are for ...

Comment: you should _NEVER_ re-invent the wheel, especially if you want to create pseudo-random data! You could use SecureRandom, for instance : http://pastebin.com/e9tuMjUd

Comment: better version (not bit-shiftin mistake) : http://pastebin.com/0zssB3iW

Comment: @specializt "um ... thats what they keywords static final are for ..." You don't understand my needs. You see, having one Random instance would return a different random value each time, but I need a method that will map x and y values to a number. For example, (3, 5) should always return 0.3 or something like that. I can't be having it returning a different number every time!

Comment: MAPPING values has nothing to do with GENERATING RANDOM NUMBERS - if mapping is what you wanted to achieve .... you didnt meet your goal. You are generating statistically weak pseudo-random numbers in `noise`. What made you think it does something else?

Comment: what you (probably) want is a MultiKeyMap : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html

Comment: @specializt Ok, no. I don't see how you still don't understand what I need, but either way I figured out the real problem. Anyway, sorry, I'm not that good at wording things correctly, but thanks for the help! :)

Comment: what you ACTUALLY tried to do was generating random colors - hence pseudorandom numbers within a range of possible values; either that or a linear, threedimensional function which adds pseudorandom data to the final result. The first option is exactly what SecureRandom does - in fact it ONLY fills bytearrays; which is perfect for RGB values. I think you have major problems spotting the exact goal of your own application ... thats certainly something a programmer should become good at, without that skill a programmer may never be a developer.

Comment: @specializt "without that skill a programmer may never be a developer" Sorry, but I have the exact goal of my application. I think I have an idea of what I was going to use this method for before I created it. I know it will suit my needs and won't hinder me from becoming a developer.

Comment: you were going to use it to create pseudo-random numbers hence reinvent the wheel. To-be programmers who reinvent the wheel will fail in their future job - i already saw a few people like that failing.

Comment: @specializt Ok seriously, just stop. You're depressing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you call `BufferedImage.getData()` it is returning a copy, not the actual backing array. So any changes you make directly to that array will not be reflected in the image.

From the [JavaDoc for BufferedImage.getData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData()):

> **Returns:**
>   a Raster that is a copy of the image data.

**Edit** What's interesting is what it says for the same method in the [Java 6 JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getData()), it's more explicit about the copy's effects. I wonder why they changed it?

> Returns the image as one large tile. The Raster returned is a copy of the image data is not updated if the image is changed

Comment: What?? It never used to work that way! I swear I've been doing this for ages!

Comment: Yes, that one seems to be calling `getRaster()` instead of `getData()`. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Haha, I think our comments crossed. Glad you figured it out! Best of luck.

Comment: @Todd Maybe they changed it because "The Raster returned is a copy of the image data is not updated if the image is changed" doesn't make grammatical sense.

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer be as simple as the changes in the data array not being reflected in `img` object?

Comment: Maybe, but it never used to do this, so I'm confused. I still have java 7

Comment: @Todd provided the more technical version of what I just said, but getting the data only returns a copy, so you will have to then turn that data array back into a BufferedImage to see the changes

Comment: Thing is, I used to always do it in this way, and it would reflect the changes all on it's own